Proving the $f^{-1}$, $f_*$ adjunction of sheaves directly
This question asks about proving the adjunction between $f^{-1}$ and $f_*$ for sheaves by showing that the unit and counit have the necessary properties by looking at stalks.
I understand the answer there as to why it suffices to look at stalks, but I get just as lost in the notation and the various direct limits when looking at stalks as I do when looking at sections. So, how do we see that the unit and counit identities hold by looking at stalks?
If it is helpful, I've defined my $\eta_\mathscr{G} : \mathscr{G} \to f_* f^{-1} \mathscr{G}$ to be the morphism given by the canonical maps $\mathscr{G}(U) \to \varinjlim_{V \supset f(f^{-1}(U))} \mathscr{G}(V)$, which exist since $U \supset f(f^{-1}(U))$; and my $\varepsilon_{\mathscr{F}} : f^{-1} f_* \mathscr{F} \to \mathscr{F}$ to be the morphism defined by the maps $\varinjlim_{V \supset f(U)} \mathscr{F} (f^{-1} (V)) \to \mathscr{F}(U)$ given by restriction $\mathscr{F}(f^{-1}(V)) \to \mathscr{F}(U)$ on every $V$, and the universal property of colimits.

Well, you could start by computing the stalks of $f^{-1}$ and $f_$. I don't think this is really a great way to do this, though - stalks of $f^{-1}$ are reasonable, but stalks of $f_$ aren't great. It's kind of a bear of a proof for the notational reasons you mention, but you can do it, you just have to sit down at a blackboard/whiteboard/large piece of paper and write everything out.

Ok, thanks! From the wording on the linked question, I thought there was maybe a slick argument with stalks that I was missing. But I guess I should finally take the time to just sit down and write everything out

Yeah, I'd probably skip the stalks and just go to showing the compositions are right on sections.  It might help to think of the elements of $f^{-1} \mathscr{F}(U)$ as $f^{-1}{U,V}(x)$ where $x \in \mathscr{F}(V)$ and $V \supseteq f(U)$ - or even as $\rho{f^{-1}(V), U}(f^{-1}(x))$ where $f^{-1}(x) \in f^{-1}\mathscr{F}(f^{-1}(V))$, though you might want to be careful with the latter.  But the former could certainly help in terms of using notation to help keep things straight, I'd guess.

Oh, I guess the stalks could be useful in reducing the sheaf case to the presheaf case, where the argument based on sections would then apply -- but IMO the easier way to reduce to the presheaf case would be to use that sheafification is the left adjoint of the inclusion functor (presheaves $\hookrightarrow$ sheaves) and then apply the standard fact about adjoints of compositions.
